# Remove the first character from an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a SQL request with `JOIN` but I have a filed where an ID is containing a letter in the first position. I need to omit it when I'm doing the request. The value of the column `service` is equal to the id of `tbl2` without the 'S' character).

Here are the table :

**tbl1**

```
-------------------
| id    | service |
-------------------
| 58186 | S83968  |
| ...   | ...     |
```

**tbl2**

```
-------------------
| id    | domain  |
-------------------
| 83968 | serv123 |
| ...   | ...     |
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT `domain` 
FROM `tbl2` 
INNER JOIN `tbl1`  
WHERE tbl2.id = tbl1.SUBSTR(service, 2)
AND id = '58186';
```

It return an error:

> .#1630 - FUNCTION tbl1.SUBSTR does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Expected result :

```
-----------
| domain  |
-----------
| serv123 |
```

Comment: I possible, fix the data model :-)

Comment: I can't change the data

Comment: That's why I wrote "if possible". A bad/wrong data model leads to problems and is a root cause for bad performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - you need to add `SUBSTR(tbl1.service, 2)` not `tbl1.SUBSTR(service, 2)`

```
  SELECT `domain` 
    FROM `tbl2` 
    INNER JOIN `tbl1`  
    WHERE tbl2.id = SUBSTR(tbl1.service, 2)
    AND tbl1.id = '58186'
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask if is it right to use inner join instead of let or right join ?

Comment: @executable, if you need the common data then it's ok to use inner join

Answer (score 2):

I actually prefer adding the `'S'` to the other id:

```
SELECT tbl2.`domain` 
FROM `tbl2` INNER JOIN
     `tbl1`  
     ON CONCAT('S', tbl2.id) = tbl1.service
WHERE tbl1.id = '58186';
```

This may seem like a small nuance.  However, in some cases `tbl2.id` could be a number.  Because of the rules of conversion, there could be situations where you get a type-conversion error (in some databases) or unexpected results (in MySQL) if any (non-matching) values in `service` cannot be converted to a number.